# Using Public Activity to Show who has been followed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, public-activity

Im using public activity to provide notifications for activities of people followed. I want to show if a user follows another in the format of

```
John Doe followed Sam Smith
```

But all I can achieve so far is

```
John Doe followed 1
```

here is my code. Relationships controller

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :authenticate_user!

 def create
  @user = User.find(params[:followed_id])
  current_user.follow(@user)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @user }
    format.js
  end
 end

 def destroy
  @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
  current_user.unfollow(@user)
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html { redirect_to @user }
   format.js
  end
 end
end
```

Relationship model

```
class Relationship < ApplicationRecord
 include PublicActivity::Model
  tracked owner: ->(controller, model) { controller && controller.current_user }

  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"

  validates :follower_id, presence: true
  validates :followed_id, presence: true
end
```

Relationship create file inside public_activity folder

```
<% if activity.trackable %>
  Followed <%= activity.trackable.followed_id %>
<% else %>
  Unfollowed a User
 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just rendering a `followed_id` you might want to render the `followed.name` instead. Change:

```
Followed <%= activity.trackable.followed_id %>
```

to something like this (replace `name` with a method that makes sense in your application):

```
Followed <%= activity.trackable.followed.name %>
```

Comment: This did it. I am also having another issue with public activity and tracking posts commented on. I have this in my create.html.erb for comment <%= link_to activity.trackable.post.body, activity.trackable.post %> the error i'm getting is undefined method `post' for nil:NilClass. Comment controller create action has if @comment.save
      @comment.create_activity :create, owner: current_user . Where might I be going awry with this

Comment: That sounds like a different, unrelated problem. Let's wrap up this question by accepting the answer if the error in your question is gone. And ask a new question and paste all relevant source code. Discussing further details here in the comments is very hard and doesn't make much sense.